# Word document Page Setup takes forever

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

the following 2 code lines cause my program to somehow not continue the rest of the methods code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
WordApp.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
document = WordApp.Documents.Add();
document.PageSetup.TopMargin = 5;
document.PageSetup.Orientation = WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;
```

The application does not freeze.
Every single breakpoint after these lines will never be reached.

If I take these lines out, the rest of the code runs through and works fine.

Comment: Word does not *really* work with pages, it must rely on the printer for this. So probably your code is waiting for a reply to some messagebox or dialog you just don't see. Try `wordApp.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;` and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: I found out that if i wait 2 minutes for each line, it finishes and the code continues. What could cause these 2 lines to take so long?

Comment: And this only seems to take this long in Debug mode. If i start the compiled exe-file it works fine.

Comment: Can't tell with only two lines of code.

Comment: Funny. I just tried this and it went zoom. Might be your Normal.dotm. Make sure all Word processes are closed. Then browse to `C:\Users\[you]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`, rename `Normal.dotm` to `Normal.old`. Try again. Still slow?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. Still slow.

Comment: I just tried to open a new word document manually and change orientation and it's taken one minute to do so. Same if i try to change the orientation back.

Comment: Wow. Try to find an updated driver for your printer.

Comment: It's a network printer at the office. I can try. But what does the printer have to do with it? I'm not trying to print anything.

Comment: The printer is used to determin the layout. Without printer, Word does not have "pages". But you are giving me another idea. Network printer. ==> Check for any outdated mapped network drives, i.e. shares that are no longer present - and check `Start==>Devices and printers` for any unavailable printers.

Comment: But then how can I use word on a computer without ever connecting any printer? This works anyway, doesn't it? Back to the problem: it looks like connecting to the printer takes very long time. If i open a new word document and hit file -> print, it also takes very long.

Comment: No real biggy with Win 7 onwards as that comes with the XPS writer, i.e. a pre-installed printer-like application similar to a PDF printer. If you had a virgin Win XP installation with nothing but a fresh Word install on it, you'd see that you couldn't activate the `Page preview` for a Word document. ;-)    ==>So yeah, probably an unreachable network destination; a disconnected share or network printer.

Comment: Changing the standard printer to be "Send to One Note" solves this issue. But I guess it's just a workaround. Seems the main problem is somewhere in our company network or the network printer. So I could delete this post?

Comment: You could or *should* first do what I recommended you to do: check for unavailable network resources! IF anyone else comes across this post s/he will certainly curse your bones if all they read is "Welp, got it with a nasty workaround."

Comment: I did. There are no unavailable network drives and the only printers I have installed are the network printer, Microsoft XPS Document Writer, Fax and Send to OneNote 2010

Comment: OK. Probably an issue with the printer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved: The problems cause was the network printer. Because word needs a connection to a printer to set Page setup and it couldn't establish the connection to the printer, it waited. Setting the default printer to another one solved the issue.

Comment: Awsome, I would have never thought that was the problem. Thanks!